# Lost my job, is it better to apply for EI or CRB?

Tags: canada, employment, employment-insurance

I was recently terminated without cause. Is it better to apply for EI, CRB or something else? The work I had been doing before COVID still hasn't returned yet. I had been working in retail for the past 6 months. I have heard it's important to apply quickly after loosing work because it could take a while to go through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This government page](https://www.canada.ca/en/department-finance/economic-response-plan.html#individuals) says that EI benefit is minimum $500/week, while CRB benefit is maximum $300/week. EI sounds better.

Other items of interest on that page:

- Mortgage payment deferral
- Provincial and territorial support